# Trying to convert this activity into a fragment in android studio, no luck till now

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment

This is my test activity and I want to convert this into a fragment.
Please guide me how to convert this activity into a fragment which is inside a tabview.
I am new bee in android app development and this is beyond my reach for now.

```js
package in.catking.catking;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class test2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    String API_KEY = "ABA"; // API owner  XYX
    String NEWS_SOURCE = "in";
    public ListView listNews;
    ProgressBar loader;

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    static final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    static final String KEY_URL = "url";
    static final String KEY_URLTOIMAGE = "urlToImage";
    static final String KEY_PUBLISHEDAT = "publishedAt";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test2);

        listNews = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listNews);
        loader = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loader);
        listNews.setEmptyView(loader);



        if(Function.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext()))
        {
            DownloadNews newsTask = new DownloadNews();
            newsTask.execute();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }


    class DownloadNews extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String xml = "";

            String urlParameters = "";//xml = Function.excuteGet("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country="+NEWS_SOURCE+"&apiKey="+API_KEY, urlParameters);
            xml = Function.excuteGet("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country="+NEWS_SOURCE+"&apiKey="+API_KEY, urlParameters);
            return  xml;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String xml) {

            if(xml.length()>10){ // Just checking if not empty

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(xml);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("articles");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put(KEY_AUTHOR, jsonObject.optString(KEY_AUTHOR).toString());
                        map.put(KEY_TITLE, jsonObject.optString(KEY_TITLE).toString());
                        map.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, jsonObject.optString(KEY_DESCRIPTION).toString());
                        map.put(KEY_URL, jsonObject.optString(KEY_URL).toString());
                        map.put(KEY_URLTOIMAGE, jsonObject.optString(KEY_URLTOIMAGE).toString());
                        map.put(KEY_PUBLISHEDAT, jsonObject.optString(KEY_PUBLISHEDAT).toString());
                        dataList.add(map);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                ListNewsAdapter adapter = new ListNewsAdapter(test2.this, dataList);
                listNews.setAdapter(adapter);

                listNews.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(test2.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("url", dataList.get(+position).get(KEY_URL));
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No news found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }



    }


}
```

this is my ListNewsAdapter

```js
package in.catking.catking;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * vvklr
 */

class ListNewsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;

    public ListNewsAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ListNewsViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ListNewsViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
            holder.galleryImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.galleryImage);
            holder.author = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.author);
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.sdetails = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sdetails);
            holder.time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ListNewsViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.galleryImage.setId(position);
        holder.author.setId(position);
        holder.title.setId(position);
        holder.sdetails.setId(position);
        holder.time.setId(position);

        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song = data.get(position);

        try{
            holder.author.setText(song.get(test2.KEY_AUTHOR));
            holder.title.setText(song.get(test2.KEY_TITLE));
            holder.time.setText(song.get(test2.KEY_PUBLISHEDAT));
            holder.sdetails.setText(song.get(test2.KEY_DESCRIPTION));

            if(song.get(test2.KEY_URLTOIMAGE).toString().length() < 5)
            {
                holder.galleryImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{
                Picasso.with(activity)
                        .load(song.get(test2.KEY_URLTOIMAGE).toString())
                        .resize(300, 200)
                        .into(holder.galleryImage);
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {}
        return convertView;
    }
}

class ListNewsViewHolder {
    ImageView galleryImage;
    TextView author, title, sdetails, time;
}
```

I am trying to convert this activity into a fragment FragmentA but I am not able to do it.
Anyone please help or suggest.

Comment: You're asking for help in converting yout Activity to a Fragment, but you also provide your Adapter's code. As I was going from using Activities to using Fragments, it was easier for me, to first understand Fragments. I would suggest, for now, you focus on the use of a Fragment. So is your Activity already working, as you want it to be?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, to convert an Activity to a Fragment, usually needs to do following things:

1. Move the layout from `activity_test2.xml` to `fragment_a.xml`. 
   If the Fragment should appear below a Toolbar in its parent Activity, add the attribute `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">` to the root Layout of the Fragment XML.
2. Move the `onCreate` code from the Activity to the `onCreateView` method inside the Fragment. Your own methods can simply be copied into the Fragment class.
3. To keep `findViewById()` working inside the Fragment, do it like this:

   ```
   public ListView listNews; 
   ProgressBar loader;

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

       listNews = rootView.findViewById(R.id.listNews);
       loader = rootView.findViewById(R.id.loader);

       return rootView;
   }
   ```
4. Replace all `getApplicationContext()` calls with `getActivity()`
5. If you have overridden any activity specific lifecycle methods, the code may need to be moved into the corresponding Fragment lifecycle method. For example, the code from `onDestroy` inside the Activity is moved to `onDestroyView` inside the Fragment. The Activity and Fragment lifecycle and how they are related can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRxIQ.png).

The `AsyncTask` inner class can simply be moved inside the Fragment class. 
As far as I can see right now, the Adapter also can stay the same. You may (not totally sure) only need to replace 
`private Activity activity;` 
with 
`private Context context`.

Hope this helps you.